# Conditional class probabilities in YOLOv1

Tags: object-detection, yolo

In YOLO v1, authors defines conditional class probabilities (P(Class_i/Object))

I don't understand that authors can define the head output to conditional class probabilities. When the model finishes training, can it be concluded that the value of the output is a probability value?